# Please explain ths recursion step by step

Tags: java, recursion

Please explain ths recursion step by step;

```
public class TestClass {

    private static void printit(int i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        printit(i / 2);
        printit(i / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 8;
        printit(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: why  and how output is   8
4
2
2
4
2
2

Comment: If you pass in 8, it's not 1, right? So the method doesn't immediately return. It then prints 8, and calls itself on 8 / 2, which is 4. Now, if you pass in 4, that's not 1, right? ... And so on. Bring out a pencil and paper, and write down exactly what each step is doing; it may help you to indent every time you invoke a method, and un-indent when it returns. I know it sounds tedious, but it's the best way to learn and internalize this stuff. And this stuff is critical, so it's time well spent.

Comment: @DeepakKataria Usually questions with `please do this`, `please do that` will be badly received. A question like `this is what I tried, can someone explain to me what went wrong?` will be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using IDE you can just use the debugger and see with you own eyes what's happening step by step.

Anyway, let's try and what happens when we call the recursive method:
You call the method with 8 (`printit(8);`):

1. `System.out.println(8);` -> 8
2. `printit(8 /2 );` -> Call to method again with 8/2=4
3. `System.out.println(4);` -> 4
4. `printit(4 /2 );` > Call to method again with 4/2=2
5. `System.out.println(2);` -> 2
6. `printit(2 /2 );` > Call to method again with 2/2=1
7. `return;` -> Continues with previous call, the (`printit(4 /2);`)
8. `printit(2 /2 );` > Call to method again with 2/2=1
9. `return;` -> Continues with previous call, the (`printit(4 /2);`)
10. method finishes, continues with the previous call (`printit(8 /2);`)
11. `printit(4 /2 );` > Call to method again with 4/2=2
12. `System.out.println(2);` -> 2
13. calls `printit(2/2);` which we already know result in nothing.
14. Now we are in the first call again, the `printit(8);`, calling for `printit(8/2);`
15. `System.out.println(4);` -> 4
16. 16 etc...

Comment: Lovely... thanks.........!!!